# How to get Parent-Child relationship by using recursive function in java

Tags: java, recursion, parent-child

I want to get parent-child relation array by using recursive function in java.
I tried some ways to display I want but it looks something wrong. pls give me some suggestions and guidelines.

I have 3 tables in my db; dept, company, depttree

dept

```
dept_cd company_cd
100     0017
101     0017
102     0017
103     0017
200     0017
201     0017
202     0017
300     0017
301     0017
302     0017
303     0017
304     0017
999     0017
```

company

```
company_cd  
0017
0018
```

depttree

```
dept_cd (Parent)    child_dept_cd
100                 101
100                 999
200                 201
200                 202
300                 301
300                 302
101                 102
102                 103
302                 303
302                 304
```

**I want to display (in console) as the followings.**

```
[100]
[100,101]
[100,101,102]
[100,101,102,103]
[100,999]
[200]
[200,201]
[200,202]
[300]
[300,301]
[300,302]
[300.302,303]
[300,302,304]
```

In my program, I wrote as the followings.

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> g_nodes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    functionA() {
       String p_DeptCd = functionB(g_ssp.g_gp.getParam("company_cd"), 0);
       //e.g: company_cd = 0017, 0 means '0017 does not have parent'
    }
    functionB(String x_dept_cd, int x_flag){
        PmsSql p_sql = new PmsSql(g_ssp);
    if (x_flag == 0) {
        p_sql.setField("dept.dept_cd, dept.dept_cd_nk, dept.dept_nm, dept.dept_disp_nm");
        p_sql.setTable("dept INNER JOIN company ON dept.company_cd = company.company_cd");
        p_sql.addWhere("dept.company_cd = ?");
        p_sql.addWhere("dept.dept_cd NOT IN (SELECT child_dept_cd FROM depttree)");
        p_sql.addWhereValue("company_cd", x_dept_cd);
        p_sql.setOrder("dept.disp_order desc");
    }
    if (x_flag == 1) {
        p_sql.setField("dept.dept_cd, dept.dept_disp_nm");
        p_sql.setTable("dept INNER JOIN depttree ON dept.dept_cd = depttree.child_dept_cd");
        p_sql.setWhere("dept.dept_cd_nk IS NOT NULL");
        p_sql.addWhere("depttree.dept_cd = ?");
        p_sql.addWhereValue("dept_cd", x_dept_cd);
        p_sql.setOrder("dept.disp_order desc");
    }
    p_sql.execQuery();
    while (p_sql.next()) {
        String p_dept_cd = p_sql.getString("dept_cd");
        ArrayList<String> p_childArr = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(x_flag == 1){
            p_childArr.add(x_dept_cd);
        }

        p_childArr.add(p_dept_cd);
        g_nodes.add(p_childArr);
        System.out.println("g_nodes = "+g_nodes);
        functionB(p_dept_cd, 1);
    }
    return null;
    }
```

but it displays like that.

```
g_nodes = [[100], [100, 999], [100, 101], [101, 102], [102, 103], [200], [200, 201], [200, 202], [300], [300, 301], [300, 302], [302, 303], [302, 304]]
```

**I'm very sorry for my long descriptions.** Thanks in advance.

Comment: does anybody help me in my question, pls?
@Roman C, pls give me some guidelines for that, if possible.

Comment: it would be easier for you to extract all records in depttree table, then displaying outputs like what you need is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe your question is overcomplicated.

1. Company has nothing to do with the question
2. DeptTree can simply seen as an extra "parent_dept" in Dept table.
3. Most columns of Dept has nothing to do with the question

So your question can be simplified to:

```
Dept
--------
DEPT_CD    PARENT_DEPT_CD
```

The biggest problem is: I don't see any recursive function in your original code.  And you haven't been clear in telling us what is your expected behavior.

If you are simply getting all dept and showing each dept with all the parents of it, you can simply put the dept (with dept code and parent dept code) in a map, using dept code as the key.  Then for each dept in the map, recursively shows parent's dept code, and then shows its own code.

something like this:

```
    //....
    for (Dept dept : deptMap.values()) {
        displayDept(dept, deptMap);
    }
    //.....

void displayDept(Dept dept, Map<String, Dept> deptMap) {
    if (dept has parent) {
       Dept parentDept = deptMap.get(dept.parent);
       displayDept(parentDept, deptMap);
    }
    display dept.code
}
```

(Just give you an idea and please write correct code yourself)

If you are using Oracle (from the SQL and convention it looks like to me), you may also consider using hierarchical query which can greatly reduce your effort to construct the hierarchy of nodes:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

Comment: Thanks, @Adrian Shum. dept_cd is the parent column in depttree. I modified the complicated mistakes in my question. I'm using the postgreSQL.

Comment: @SandarMinAye I understand your depttree.  What I mean is, conceptually it can be simplified to what I have mentioned.  If you can figure out how to do in my example, there should be no problem to change to your case (dept+parentDept is nothing but joining dept and depttree).  And, a brief search in "PostgreSQL hierarchical query" seems suggests that Hierarchical Query is available in PostgreSQL too.